# Change label rendering in CategoryAxis

Tags: wpf, silverlight, charts, wpftoolkit, silverlight-toolkit

I have a chart with ColumnSeries and I am trying to make the labels on X axis display near the ticks like this:

[image: Goal]

By default, the ColumnSeries uses CategoryAxis axis which places labels in the middle of interval:

[image]

What I want is the X axis to work similar to LinearAxis. However I don't see any way to make ColumnSeries use LinearAxis.

Also, I see no way how to render the labels to be placed near the ticks. I can go and modify the source code of CategoryAxis but it is not easy to me.

Another idea I had was to use a LinearAxis but doesn't seem to work with ColumnSeries.

Any idea is much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: The 2011, 2012 are just examples, they are not dates. What I am trying to do actually is display intervals on X axis. 2011 should actually start in origin. I will update the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ColumnSeries` works correctly with a `LinearAxis`.  Here is an example modified from Delay's [DataVisualizationDemos](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/22/nobody-likes-a-show-off-today-s-datavisualizationdemos-release-includes-new-demos-showing-off-stacked-series-behavior.aspx) sample:

[image]

The XAML:

```xml
<chartingToolkit:Chart Title="Stock Performance">
    <!-- Stock price and volume -->
    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries
        Title="ABCD"
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource SalesDataCollection}"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding EastStoreQuantity}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding WestStoreQuantity}"
        />
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <!-- Axis for custom labels -->
        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="10"
            Interval="1"
            Orientation="X">
        </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

The code-behind:

```
public class SalesDataCollection : Collection<SalesData>
{
    public SalesDataCollection()
    {
        Add(new SalesData { Animal = "Dogs", WestStoreQuantity = 5, EastStoreQuantity = 7 });
        Add(new SalesData { Animal = "Cats", WestStoreQuantity = 5, EastStoreQuantity = 6 });
        Add(new SalesData { Animal = "Birds", WestStoreQuantity = 3, EastStoreQuantity = 8 });
        Add(new SalesData { Animal = "Fish", WestStoreQuantity = 6, EastStoreQuantity = 9 });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not intending to display dates on X axis. They are actually interval values like -1, -2, -3, -4, -5. It's a histogram chart displaying bars and having intervals on X axis . Sorry if I wasn't clear. Any idea how to do that? Note that first axis label must start from origin.

Comment: I converted the sample to use a `LinearAxis`.

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing wrong or how do I end up to the conclusion that LinearAxis doesn't work for ColumnSeries. It must be too much work, for too long. I am such an idiot. Thanks alot!

Comment: I have an issue. The LinearAxis doesn't display the Minimum when Minimum is a fractional value, like -1.7